# Users schema with poking other users schema in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am making an application in which a user can poke other users. Here is the code for the schema designs I have considered. The first is using only a `users` schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({ 
  name: { type : String},
  pokes: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null}],
});
```

Another way is using a `pokes` schema. Here I'm storing the object `ids` of the `pokes` schema in the `users` schema.

```
const pokesSchema = new Schema({ 
  from_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
  to_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
});

const userSchema = new Schema({ 
  name: { type : String},
  pokes: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pokes' ,default:null}],
});
```

In the third way I totally remove the relation between the two schemas:

```
const pokesSchema = new Schema({ 
  from_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
  to_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
});

const userSchema = new Schema({ 
  name: { type : String},
});
```

In the second and third ways I can query for pokes easily.
I want to know which of the three is the best design and why. Also if `userA` pokes `userB` then it can be the case that `userB` can also poke back to `userA`. I'm learning `node.js` currently and am confused about the design in `mongoDb`.

Comment: The best design depends on what you are going to do with the data. Will you mostly be adding pokes? Will you mostly be reading pokes? Will you be interested in getting the list of all pokes? Etc. And then - How often? How often relative to each other? Data design is unrelated to node.js but is a useful skill on its own :)

Comment: Three function will be called more...add pokes...read pokes...get pokes

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here's the best I can do. You briefly answered my question in my comment above but I'd like to point out it's important to think about what you are doing (or expect to be doing) *more* and *how much more*. That aside though, let's take a look at each schema.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({ 
    name: { type : String},
    pokes: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null}],
});
```

When we look at this first one it seems inadequate for your needs. It's a collection of users who have a name and an array of pokes they have made. If we need to know who a user has poked then that's a really easy and fast query - it's right there under their name, search by `name` or `_id` and we're done! But what happens when you want to look up who has poked this user? **You will need to query every single user and then search through every single pokes array for the original user**. If we have m-many users and each has n-many pokes, that's doing m* n tests. Yikes. If m and n get big that's going to be *a lot* (think of the difference of 100 * 100 vs 10,000 * 10,000 or even more!). Even if you personally are not coding that search in your node then mongo is doing that search. So unless you're sure that looking up who has poked a user is going to be something that is pretty rare this is probably not a good option. Moving on:

```
const pokesSchema = new Schema({ 
    from_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
    to_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
});

const userSchema = new Schema({ 
    name: { type : String},
    pokes: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pokes' ,default:null}],
});
```

Now we have a pokes schema, nice! If we wanted to do the search we discussed above we can instead query pokes directly based on `to_user_id`, and then if we need a name of all the users who initiated the pokes we can just query the users based on its `_id`. Not bad! We also still have the fast way to get the reverse, aka search for pokes a user has initiated, because there is still `pokes` in our user schema. What happens when a poke occurs, though? **We have to update both schemas**. So not only will we do a (relatively easy) insert into pokes, we will have to also update our pokes array of the user who did the poking. This might not be so bad, but what happens if one update fails? Now *our data is inconsistent* - users and pokes don't match. We're also doubling our updates every poke. This might not be a big deal, and if we're getting a user's pokes much more than we're poking then it might be an ok trade-off, but it becomes a little riskier because we've introduced somewhere we can be inconsistent. Alright, last one:

```
const pokesSchema = new Schema({ 
    from_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
    to_user_id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' ,default:null},
});

const userSchema = new Schema({ 
  name: { type : String},
});
```

First, note that these schemas are *still related* - the pokes schema reference users. It's just not doubly-related like the last one. Anyway, now we've removed the pokes array from the user schema. Ok! We don't run the risk of having inconsistent data anymore, noice! We're also not doing two updates for every poke, toit! The trade-off is now when we want to get the list of users a user has poked we have to do a similar query to the one we did above when we wanted to get a list of users a user has been poked by. Which isn't so bad, but is certainly not as fast as having the pokes array already sitting there and waiting.

In my opinion, unless you're searching for who users have poked (and not been poked by) significantly more often than doing anything else this third scenario is best. The schemas make logical sense, you're not updating twice. It's what I would use. But as I said, it's very important to consider your particular need and design.

Hope that helps!